# discord python bot never awaited

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is part of the code of my main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from os import listdir

for filename in listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

And this code is a cog, which is added to the main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json

class GameCommands(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    def leerjson(self):
        jugador = None
        with open("cogs/personajes.json", 'r') as contenido:
            jugador = json.load(contenido)
        return jugador

    def inventario(self, jugador, idmem):
        casillas = ":x::one: :two: :three: :four: :five: :six: :seven: :eight: :nine:\n:one:"
        for i in range(27):
            if "name" in jugador[idmem]["slot"][i]:
                casillas = casillas + jugador["objetos"][jugador[idmem]["slot"][i]["name"]]
            else:
                casillas = casillas + ":blue_square:"
            if i == 8:
                casillas = casillas + "\n\n:two:"
            if i == 17:
                casillas = casillas + "\n\n:three:"
        return casillas

    @commands.command(aliases=['inv', 'objetos', 'obj'])
    async def inventario(self, ctx):
        p = self.leerjson()
        if str(ctx.message.author.id) in p:
            inv = self.inventario(p, ctx.message.author.id)
            inventario = discord.Embed(
                title="Inventario",
                color = discord.Colour.blue()
            )
            inventario.add_field(name=ctx.message.author, value=inv)
            await ctx.send("hola",embed=inventario)
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention} Aún no has creado un personaje, usa `prb>empezar` para hacerlo.')
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(GameCommands(bot))
```

When I try to call the command "inventario" the embed variable (inventario) is sent, but at the same time I get this error.

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py:83: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: What other files do you have in `.../cogs`? Maybe you have a `.py` file in there that isn't a cog file and that's why it cannot load it.

Comment: At the moment, I only have that file in .../cogs